# CSS background-image persudo responsive with absolute position

Tags: css, background-image

Ok this is really stumping me, probably because i don't understand it 100%. I have the following code to display a responsive background-image on the header:

```
 .home .site-header-main:before{

    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url('/images/home-menu/home_honey_drip.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    padding-top: 35%;

 }
```

What i want it to do is display the 'home_honey_drip.png' under the menu text and then 'overflow' it over the top of the body content. I have tried adding `position: absolute;` However the image disappears.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you add some more HTML/CSS and possibly a working example to show us where you are at the moment.

Comment: Is it possible to create a jsfiddle showing the problem?

Comment: Ok try this: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guyj91/a6mf5tak/) it looks like jsfiddle doesn't like the :before handle. Does that help? - i want the background image to display over the 'main' div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use position relative and move the content of the menu to top.

You can do this using two divs, one with the image and other with the menu content.

```
#menu{ 
    top:-100px; 
    position: relative;
    color:white;
}
```

You can check my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kinari/a5fktpv3/1/). Just add the rest of the css you need to your image.

Comment: Thanks! i didn't even think of trying it that way.